# What would we get if we differentiate $\exp(x)$ infinitely many times?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

If we considered the exponential functions $\exp(x)$ which is differentiable infinitely many times, what can we say on the limit
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{d^n}{dx^n} (\exp(x))\ ? $$

If we write $\exp(x)$ as the Taylor extension can we say that the limite is approaching $0$? Since:

[image]

Comment: I believe you're a bit confused about how power series work. You can "add infinite zeroes before", but the $0$-th term of the series still sums up to $1$. The Taylor series of $\exp(x)$ remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't say that. If $f$ is the exponential function and $x \in \mathbb R$, then $f^{(n)}(x) = e^x$ for every positive integer $n$. So, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^{(n)}(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^x = e^x$.

---

**Comment**: If
$$
a_n = a_{n,1} + a_{n,2} + a_{n,3} + \cdots
$$
for every positive integer $n$, then it might be tempting to think that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,1} + \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,2} + \cdots.
$$
However, as this example shows, that is simply false.

Comment: Hmm, I would argue you cannot just say ${\lim_{n\to \infty}f^{(n)}(x)=e^x}$ since we haven't even defined what we mean by this limit in this context. The question doesn't make sense without further specification

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose The way I phrased my answer, $x$ is a fixed real number. And for each positive integer $n$, $f^{(n)}(x)$ is a number (it is the $n$th derivative of $f$ evaluated at $x$). So we are just taking the limit of a sequence of numbers.

Comment: Ahh I see, you are doing a pointwise limit here and essentially just getting a sequence of numbers (which is always just going to be a constant sequence). This definitely defines the limit I guess, it's just this justification / definition was not given by OP so I was confused

Answer (score 0):

For your first question *all* the derivatives are the same thing $e^x$ so the limit would be that too.

For your second question all the series will be the same as $e^x$ since inserting any finite number of zeroes before an infinite sum has no effect on the sum value.

Comment: Hmm.. I would argue that the limit doesn't even make sense in this context? Like, we haven't defined what we mean by ${\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)}$?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Surely a limit of an expression which depends on $x$ and  $n,$ as in this case where the expression is the $n$th derivative of a function $f(x),$, where $f$ is infinitely differentiable at every $x,$ makes sense in the sense that for each particular $x$ it is a sequence of reals.

Comment: I completely agree it does yes, but this isn't defined by OP

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful with notation here. What exactly do you mean by ${\frac{d^{\infty}}{dx^{\infty}}}$?

Without defining what you mean here the question doesn't even make sense. It's certainly true (and you can prove by induction) that for any ${n \in \mathbb{N}}$ we have ${\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^x=e^x}$, but that's it.

Another point to make is that **you cannot sum an "infinite" number of zeroes and conclude the answer is $0$**.

---

**EDIT**: I guess just to really explicitly answer the question "What would we get if we differentiate ${e^x}$ infinitely many times?" - the answer is it depends how you define taking the derivative infinitely many times. We cannot physically do things infinitely many times in Mathematics, and so have to create definitions to work around it. The same sort of reasoning applies here. You must define what you mean first.

Comment: There is no sum of an infinite number of $0$'s in this limit.

Comment: @coffeemath OP's last line contains an infinite number of $0$'s....

Comment: It does as you say contain a sequence of $0$'s followed by three dots, and in that sense contains an infinite number of $0$'s. But this may be due just to the OP not being that at home with expressing the limit of a series in terms of its partial sums.

Comment: @coffeemath right, but that's my point I guess. The fact is, OP did not state they were viewing the sequence as simply a sequence of real numbers (even though I completely agree it would make sense to do this), they simply said "what's the limit?" - which implies in a way they might have thought it may have some self-evident meaning attached to it, which simply isn't true. And to the point of "OP not being at home with partial sums" <- this doesn't really matter. When calculating any limit, you should be careful and do this, not doing this means you have not calculated the limit correctly

Comment: Riem... Yes I see the point of your last comment.

Comment: @coffeemath I do completely agree the whole sequence of reals things is a very good definition of what we mean here and makes complete sense. All I was trying to emphasize for OP is that it's important to be careful about what they mean here, that's all